# Encrypt URL to that user cant read that

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, encryption

I have a senerio in what i have to encrypt URL so that user cant read that.
For example i have a url at  server side,

```
http://testserver/admin/read/myvideo.mp3
```

This url i render in html page so that my javascript can pick it up and pass to my player.

Now the problem is that, any one can see that url from View source of my page.

What i want is to secure that, like i encrypt that at server side before rendering to html and in my java script use the same logic to decrypt it again and send to my player

can any body tell me any engine that works on both side and i dont have to do much work?

EDIT:
I know it will be visible from Fiddler, JS and Fire Bug but not that easy to read as compare to what is right now

Comment: Next to pointless because any good network analysis tool would be able to see the unencrypted request anyhow. Infact both Firebug and Chrome would probably show it in their network screens.

Comment: Your JavaScript is also available to the users, how can you prevent somebody from going through it and decrypting the URL ?

Comment: @dystroy Yeh I added that later, figured they would.

Comment: How about checking that the actual request to stream comes from your player? That might provide some additional protection.

Comment: yes i knw that, but for time beig i just want to encrypt that

Comment: @user788592 The point is why bother with the extra work/code that's next to useless in the long run.

Comment: @ Lloyd for many reasong, such that crawlares and bots dont get that or user can get that by seeing view source

Comment: @user788592 You can `POST` some data to the server(`http://testserver/admin/read`) with javascript, something like
`{request:"video",id=123456}` to get the video. This would prevent people from directly copying the url and pasting to a browser.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should consider generating something like one-time urls which get invalid after the first get. That would prohibit sharing that url.

Comment: I prefer this solution. Though for a streaming video that might not work out so well.

Comment: Perhaps you can leave the url valid for a longer time only for the ip which accessed it first or something like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have javascript which will decrypt the URL, then a competent miscreant could also use that javascript to decrypt the URL. You should probably check the origin of the requests to your files.

However, if you really want to do it, then you could use a [Vigenere cipher](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%25C3%25A8re_cipher&ei=cik_ULGhFYizhAeK1YDwDA&usg=AFQjCNH25BDT8a9TiGhmcJ37NVcFlVs1TA). I've used this in the past (many years ago) when I needed to make something impossible for a person to read/decipher. In my case it suited my needs as the user base was very carefully controlled and supervised. You can't really make it impossible for a computer to crack.

I've found an online javascript implementation.

Have a look here: http://www.nayuki.io/page/vigenere-cipher-javascript

Enter your URL and also a key. You'll see that it's not a simple substitution cipher.

e.g. with a key of `user788592`, `http://testserver/admin/read/myvideo.mp3` goes to `blxg://nwwkmwvmyj/eugar/iysh/dsnmuyg.qg3`

Comment: That would not stop an attacker from trivially finding out the URL using a network trace tool (WireShark, Fiddler, etc). Secondly, I don't even think it would prevent someone from deciphering it manually - in the Javascript you have the payload, the algorithm, and the secret key, so it shouldn't take long to reverse the payload. By definition, you have to use a two-way encryption, as the client needs the plaintext URL to make the request.

Comment: @RB: That's absolutely correct. I'm not suggesting that this is remotely secure, but it would probably stop a lot of people. But if you or I wanted to capture his URLs, there's probably no way he can prevent that! Although he could inspect where we're requesting them from...

Comment: If we just wanted to "stop a lot of people" then a simple substitution cipher would work - uncrackable for 99% I suspect, even with full implementation details ;-)

Comment: Lol! I think you're probably right. I reckon the Vigenere method stops a few more people, but the very definition of the problem means it can't be solved!